# Android Studio doesn't recognize device on MacOS even though adb recognizes it

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, debugging

Hi I am running **Mac OS 10.15.3** and I wanna debug my app from **Android Studio 3.6.1** to my **Nexus 5**. But Android Studio for for some reason doesn't recognize device even though if I run `adb devices` it lists my device and says that it is connected. I checked USB settings in phone and I enabled debugging and tried setting MTP and PTP. Also in Android Studio under "Device File Explorer" I see error message saying:

> "Error Initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge not found.

Even though it is installed and I can issue `adb` commands through terminal.

Did anyone had this issue with MacOS and Android Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is related to the last update of Android Studio. Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60872065/8083220.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the tools are up to date.

Find this icon in the top-right of Android Studio.

[image]

It opens `Android SDK` menu. Now, click on the `SDK Tools` pane.

[image]

Update all the outdated tools that you can and retry.
I now this is not the best answer but give it a try.

Comment: Nope, this didn't solve the issue, I assume that it might be related to Mac USB type C connection or Android Studio, because I am using original USB cable also tried to use One Plus 6 phone which also wasn't recognized.