# Android Studio not communicating with emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I'm on a mac and I updated Android Studio to the latest available version (3.6.1) and now it can't seem to connect to any emulator. I started a new Hello World project and tried building and running it. It opens the emulator but the app never runs. Logcat displays "no connected devices".

I re-installed SDK platform tools and made sure adb was running. Killed and restarted the adb service several times. Tried a different AVD. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio. I even tried rolling back to Android Studio 3.5. Logcat continues to show "no connected devices" and emulator opens but does nothing.

Not getting any helpful error messages so I don't know what else to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last update has relocated adb and other tools from **~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/** to **~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools/**.

Move (or copy) files from **.../platform-tools/platform-tools/** to **.../platform-tools**.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Is this a goof on their part? Seems like a pointless change

Comment: I think that this is a bug and we will see an update with a fix soon.